# What delivers a Parameter to a method like ...(myClass.FINALOBJECT)?

Tags: java, object, parameters, java-8, instance

I'm a student from Germany so sorry for bad language maybe.

I got an exercise from my lecturer in java basics and have a problem in understanding.
He already teached us the basics about OOP so I know how to produce an object of a desired class for example with `ClassX myObject = new ClassX ();` and simple stuff like that.

But now in this new exercise we have to create a tool which visualizes sorting algorithms und analyses the complexity. The lecturer gave us some help to realise this by telling us:

**A possible way a user could use the tool could be:**

```
SortingTool sTool = new SortingTool();
sTool.setInitData(10,false);
sTool.performExperiment(Algorithms.INSERTIONSORT);
```

I'm pretty sure he meant us to make a class called `Algorithms` and in it to construct a final object of it like this:

```
public class Algorithms {

      public final static Algorithms INSERTIONSORT = new Algorithms ();
```

Could someone pls explain how this works in general? And especially what the `performExperiment` -class of `sTool` should get from the object `INSTERTIONSORT`.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Your professor asked you to write an enum which would define the algorithms you are going to visualise.

Comment: like `enum Algorithms {
        INSERTION_SORT,
        BUBBLE_SORT;
    }`

Comment: Each enum constant can contain a reference to a corresponding algorithm implementation. It could be a method or a separate class.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Answer (score 1):

It may be something like this

```
interface Algorithms {

  public static Algorithms INSERTION_SORT = new InsertionSort();         

  void sort(List<Integer> data);
}

public class InsertionSort implements Algorithms {
    public void sort(List<Integer> data) {
        // do insertion sort 
    }
}
```

And `sTool.performExperiment()` should look like this

```
performExperiment(Algorithms algo) {
    algo.sort(data);
}
```

Comment: He didn't mention the commands `interface` and `... implements ...` so it must be a bit different. But I got a clue what to do thanks for the quick response!